# Threading in C# produces errors

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using this code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string response = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(
        () => textBox1.AppendText(response + "\r\n")
    ));
}

ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(ThreadWork.DoWork);
Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
myThread.Start();
```

but am getting lots of errors:

> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'ThreadStart' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\alexluvsdanielle\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 31 44
>   WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error 3 The name 'ThreadWork' does not exist in the current context
>   C:\Users\alexluvsdanielle\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 31 56
>   WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error 4 The type or namespace name 'Thread' could not be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>   C:\Users\alexluvsdanielle\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 32 31
>   WindowsFormsApplication1
>
> Error 5 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1.myThreadDelegate'
>   C:\Users\alexluvsdanielle\AppData\Local\Temporary
>   Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\Form1.cs 32 38
>   WindowsFormsApplication1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: do you have a `using System.Threading;` line in that file?

Comment: Your threading code block is not in a method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps I'm mentioning the bleedin' obvious here, but from the code example, your code block:

```
ThreadStart myThreadDelegate = new ThreadStart(ThreadWork.DoWork);
Thread myThread = new Thread(myThreadDelegate);
myThread.Start();
```

Is not in a method. I have done this before.

Once you have fixed this, the other answers will obviously then apply.

Comment: Wow - I'd assumed that bit was just a matter of posting snippets of the code :)

Answer (score 6):

`Thread` and `ThreadStart` are in `System.Threading` [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx).

Add `using System.Threading;` to the namespaces at the top of your code.

`ThreadWork` is not a class defined in .NET. I've found an MSDN page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) where it's used in the example code. So you need to replace it with the name of your class where you've defined your `DoWork` method. If it's in the same class as this code then you just need to pass `DoWork`.

Answer (score 2):

Missing `using System.Threading` in your code file.

Answer (score 2):

Others have given the solution to this particular problem, but the real answer to "What am I doing wrong?" is (IMO) "You're not reading the error message." Error messages are there for a reason: as hints to tell you what's wrong.

You've got several error messages like this:

> The type or namespace name '*Fpp*'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

The error message is giving you a hint here: it can't find the type, but that may be because you haven't got the right references or `using` directives. So check your references, and check your `using` directives. In this case `Thread` is in `mscorlib` so you're very unlikely to have an assembly reference problem - so the next thing to check is your `using` directives. It's in the `System.Threading` namespace, so you need

```
using System.Threading;
```

at the top - or of course you could just specify System.Threading.Thread everywhere, but that's a bit long-winded.

Reading error messages carefully will usually means you don't need to ask what you're doing wrong: they will tell you, as they have done here.

The fix for the `ThreadWork` error is harder to determine - you should be using whatever method you want to be executed in the new thread... assuming you actually want to start a new thread yourself. Are you sure you really do?

Comment: I think `ThreadWork` comes from some of the example code on the MSDN, for example on this page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes - my point is that it's harder to say what the code should actually be, as we don't know what the OP's new thread is meant to do.

Comment: jon ,actually at what speed you type ?

Answer (score 1):

for start make sure that you have a

```
using System.Threading;
```

on the top of the file.

In addition - you cannot call `myThread.Start();` outside a method.

Answer (score 1):

You should put the following code at the top of your C# code-file:
`using System.Threading`